# Find and Replace Hyperlinks in Google Document

Tags: google-docs

I have a Google Doc with tons of hyperlinks within various text strings throughout the document. All the links have the same root URL (say, my.oldsite.com). Recently the site changed their root URL to my.**newsite**.com and now I need to change all the links to the new root. So I want to FIND 'my.oldsite.com' and REPLACE with 'my.newsite.com'. The built-in Find and Replace is not working for me, hoping someone knows a way.

Comment: I was able to find-and-replace the text of web addresses. Your issue might be something simple; in the "Find and replace" dialog box, make sure you've spelled my.oldsite.com correctly, you are searching "All sheets" instead of a range, and you don't have any other options selected (like Match case, Match entire cell contents, etc.).

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to do it natively in Google Docs. Maybe you should use a Docs add-on that could do it.

This add-on allows you to do it (Link URL and Set Link URL) but it is not free, though it is only $5:
[Advanced Find & Replace](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-find-replace/ndeggoajhgnjgkjaoaepmgbpmejhdhnp?hl=en-US)

Comment: Apart from installing a commercial plugin, I'm not finding the function that does this, can you elaborate your answer?

Comment: Google Docs does not have a feature like that, so I wrote that add-ons might have, but I only found one that costs money.

Comment: Yeah, but as far as I can see that one doesn't have that feature either

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to handle with this.

First, delete the format by selecting the range you want, right-click on the selection and click the remove link option

Then you can make your replacement

And finally, you can use a link with a proper format and copy and paste the format and apply it to your selection (this last step, if you want that your links are underlined and blue)

Comment: This only works if your link text is the same as your URL. It won't work if your link text is something else.